# Examine the function $f(x)=\tan^2(\arccos x)$

Tags: derivatives

How to find the maximum domain of the function $f(x)=\tan^2(\arccos x)$. Show that $f(x)$ is a rational function. Calculate $f'(x)$ and discuss the monotony of $f$. Draw the graph of $\arccos$ and Graph of $f$. Give the image of $f$.

Note: Use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x =1$

How to do it?

Is maximum domain? $[–1, 1]$
Can someone explain me how to prove that function is rational? 
Derivate of this function is $-2/x^3$, how to discuss the monotony?
Graph is here. Can someone help me with rest? Thank you.
[Graph of f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3kOT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the fact that $\tan\phi=\sin\phi/\cos\phi$. So you have:

$$\tan^2\arccos x = {\sin^2\arccos x\over\cos^2\arccos x}$$

and then since $\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi = 1$ you have $\sin^2\phi = 1-\cos^2\phi$ so:
$$\tan^2\arccos x = {1-\cos^2\arccos x\over\cos^2\arccos x}$$

Then you use that $\cos$ is the inverse of $\arccos$ and the domain of $\arccos$ is $[-1,1]$ (which means that $\cos\arccos x = x$ if $-1\le x\le 1$). So

$$\tan^2\arccos x = {1-x^2\over x^2} = {1\over x^2}-1$$

The derivate of $1/x^2-1=x^{-2}-1$ is $-2x^{-3}$. Since the derivate is negative for positive $x$ and positive for negative $x$, $f$ will be increasing for $x<0$ and decreasing for $x>0$.

The maximal domain is of course a subset of $[-1,1]$ since that's the domain of $\arccos\phi$. Since the domain of $\tan\phi$ is the entire $\mathbb R$ except for values of $\phi$ where $\cos\phi=0$ so the range is restricted to whenever $\arccos x\ne 0$ which is when $x\ne 0$. So the range is $[-1,0)\cup(0,1]$.